# Retorno da escala original em uma função predição

Tags: r, regressão

Criei uma função simples para realizar predição das alturas de árvores através de modelos de regressão construídos para este fim (modelos de relação hipsométrica). A função realiza a predição das alturas, e as insere em uma nova coluna no data.frame mesclando-as com as alturas utilizadas para o ajuste do modelo, porém alguns modelos de relação hipsométrica alteram a escala original das alturas (variável resposta), como por exemplo modelos que utilizam log. Teria algum modo de fazer com que a função `predict` ( por exemplo), retorne os valores na escala original, identificando no modelo o fator de alteração da escala?

A função é a seguinte :

```
pp <-           
  function(model,data)
  { 
{
  vetor <- data[is.na(data$AltMed),]        
  vetor <- predict (model,vetor)    

  data$ALTMISTA <- data$AltMed          
  data$ALTMISTA[is.na(data$ALTMISTA)] <- vetor
}

return (data)       
}
```

Os modelo com que eu estou me deparando, são os seguintes:

`modelo 1 = lm(log(Altura) ~ I(1/Dap) + log(AlturaD), data=data)`

`modelo 2 = nls(I(Altura/AlturaD) ~ a1*(1-a2*exp(-a3*I(Dap/Q))), data=data, start=list(a1=3.348296, a2=-11.675862, a3=1.88852))`

Estes modelos, alteram a escala da variável resposta.

Comment: Sim, teria, mas sem um exemplo concreto é praticamente impossível ajudar.

Comment: Você pode ver sobre um exemplo reproduzível aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/825#825

Comment: Olá, eu editei minha pergunta.

Comment: @Florestal, seu exemplo não é reprodutível. O ideal era eu poder copiar e colar seu código e ver qual é o problema. Eu não conseguirei gerar seu modelo sem seus dados. O ideal seria gerar um pequeno data.frame por simulação, fazer um pequeno modelo e mostrar seu problema.